# eclipse pydev debug not working variables and breakpoints

Tags: linux, variables, debugging, breakpoints, pydev

Eclipse pydev debug - not working variables and breakpoints. It works only when breakpoints set in first line of the code. I have linux Arch, Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, pydev 7.5 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: debug config]

Comment: I didn't really understand the answer... you mean you put a breakpoint and it's not being hit?

Comment: Sorry, I am reinstall Eclipse and everything is ok. Thanks